# Initialize Class variables in Pharo Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm having trouble initializing class variables in Pharo. I started by creating a class with a single class variable:

```
Object subclass: #ClassVariableTestBehavior
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: 'test'
    package: 'DummyPackage'
```

And then on the class side I created an `initialize` message and set the variable to nil.

```
ClassVariableTestBehavior class >>> initialize
    test := nil
```

I saved and then created an instance method:

```
ClassVariableTestBehavior >>> test
    ^ test
```

and went back again and changed the class method to be:

```
ClassVariableTestBehavior class >>> initialize
    test := 34
```

In the playground I then printed the result of the following:

```
ClassVariableTestBehavior new test.
```

Which was `nil`. Why hasn't the value of the class variable updated to be 34?

Comment: BTW. It is a good practice to distinguish class variables (from instance variables) by capitalizing them. In Smalltalk lowercase letters indicate encapsulation. Uppercase identifiers denote a broader scope.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia good point!

Answer (score 6):

The `class>>initialize` method is used only once, when the code is initially loaded from an external file. It does not get run every time the method is edited. (If you modified a comment would you want the data to get wiped out!?) In fact, the `nil` value didn't come from your method but was just the initial default value.

A common convention is to add a comment to the initialize method with a line of code that could be executed.

```
"
ClassVariableTestBehavior initialize.
"
```

Comment: Ah interesting. I'm trying to have some variables shared for many instances. Would a better approach be messages defined on the instance side that return constants?

Comment: Class variables are shared for all instances so may be appropriate. Then the question of how to make it available. Within the class they can be referenced directly. Outside the class they will need an accessor/getter in order to be accessed. This can be done with a class or instance method (in either case `^Foo`). The class-side method might be more useful since a client wouldn't need to have an instance to get the constant. 

Of course, if it is a true constant then it could be hard-coded in a method and I'd be inclined to put it on the class side with an instance-side accessor.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused about initialize.  Based on your comment you want to create a constant value shared among the instances.

The `initialize` is usually a method for defining values for instance of an object you are creating.  The issue with Smalltalk is that not every Smalltalk implementation runs `initialize` when creating an instance; so watch out for this one.

If you want to share value among instances you can create a class method like this:

`ClassVariableTestBehavior class >> #test`

Where:

```
test
  "Class method returning always the same value"
  ^ 34
```

When you want to access the value you simply do:

`ClassVariableTestBehavior test.`

If you want to access it when you have your own instance create it you can do it like this:

```
| instance |
instance := ClassVariableTestBehavior new.
instance class test. "This accesses the class variable"
```

### **Edit** - due to excellent comment by Leandro, which I forgot to mention.

You should use capital letter for the class variable! (credit to Leandro)

If you would like to have a value stored in a class variable instead of just constant value in a method as I have shown above.  You can do it using class variable.

If you define class variable as `Test`, then you need to have a getter and setter for it.

You would have:

`ClassVariableTestBehavior class >> #test`

```
test
  "returns value of class variable"
  ^ Test
```

`ClassVariableTestBehavior class >> #test:`

```
test: aNumber
  "sets the value of class variable"
  Test := aNumber
```

You would access the value the same way as above (just before the edit).